# write() with Python and give the files a specific name

Tags: python, rename, file-rename

The following Python code extracts images from a Pdf file and saves them as jp2 files. The files are then named `im1.jp2` and `im2.jp2` and seem to be overwritten with a new pdf file from the path on the next run.
How can I give the jp2 files a specific name within the `Write()` method? E.g. `pathname_im1.jp2`? Or is it possible to rename it directly?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from pathlib import Path

pdfdirpath = Path('C:/Users/...')

pathlist = pdfdirpath.glob('*.pdf')

for path in pathlist:
    reader = PdfReader(path)
    for page in reader.pages:
        for image in page.images:
            with open(image.name, "wb") as fp:
                fp.write(image.data)
```

Comment: To prevent overwriting, check to see if a file with the name you want to use already exists, and if it does, try another.

Comment: Use Enumerate in the last for loop and append the index in file name to prevent duplicates and overwriting.

Comment: This couses another problem: "'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'"; Without "enumerate()" this problem did not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are actually a lot of good ways to do this. As it was pointed out in the comments, you could just use an `enumerate`:

```python
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from pathlib import Path

pdfdirpath = Path('C:/Users/...')

pathlist = pdfdirpath.glob('*.pdf')

for path in pathlist:
    reader = PdfReader(path)
    for page in reader.pages:
        for index, image in enumerate(page.images):
            filename = f'{index}{image.name}'
            with open(filename, "wb") as fp:
                fp.write(image.data)
```

Or you could append the `datetime` (which I think is better and more reliable across different runs, if you haven't anything better to use).

```python
from datetime import datetime

from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from pathlib import Path

pdfdirpath = Path('C:/Users/...')

pathlist = pdfdirpath.glob('*.pdf')

# Note this will use the same datetime for all images
date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

for path in pathlist:
    reader = PdfReader(path)
    for page in reader.pages:
        for image in page.images:
            filename = f'{date}_{image.name}'
            with open(filename, "wb") as fp:
                fp.write(image.data)
```

You can then modify this based on how exactly you want the thing.